# Laravel 5.2 how to send back $data along with old inputs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2.  Is this a legitimate statement?

```
   return back()->with($data)->withInput();
```

I am trying to return back to the previous page and repopulate the form using withInput.  How would I send back some data alongside the inputs?  And how would I access the $data inside my view?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `->with('data', [$data])` to set the data and then use `session('data')` in the view to access it. The data from `->withInput()` can be accessed with `old('fieldname')`